# Is there a minimum requirement for a character to have line of effect with Shadow Jaunt/Stride/Blink?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle, line-of-effect

I'm pretty sure this has been asked already but I can't find the question in question, so I hope I don't break any rules by asking again.

The Shadow X maneuvers from Shadow Hand have a line of effect and line of sight requirement to work. Let's say I want to teleport through a hole in a wall. According to both line rules, as long as I can see though the hole and there is nothing obstructing the path though the hole, I should be able to teleport though it.

Is there a minimum size the hole has to be for my character to be able to traverse the hole?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [rules for line of effect](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#lineofEffect),

> An otherwise solid barrier with a hole of at least 1 square foot through it does not block a spell’s line of effect. Such an opening means that the 5-foot length of wall containing the hole is no longer considered a barrier for purposes of a spell’s line of effect.

Technically, this is in the rules for magic and spells, which these maneuvers are not, but that’s simply how 3.5e goes—a lot of fairly fundamental things that apply well beyond magic and spells are nonetheless described in that section, for that context.

Comment: Ooooh, so that's where I read it. Somehow I missed that last line when I read it last time.